Anki collection stats is showing reviews from years before I started
When I look at my collection stats, it's showing some reviews from years before I started anki which should be impossible.

How can I search for the card causing these phantom reviews and delete them?

Is the x-axis days and you started about a year and a month or two ago?

@Tommi Yes it is. There were no other reviews between 440 and 1360 days ago.

After carefully consulting the manual, I found out how to search for cards that were first reviewed between a range of dates. For example to find cards that were introduced between 100-101 days ago you do:
-introduced:100 introduced:101

Which will include cards introduced within the last 101 days and exclude cards introduced within the last 100 days. However, this doesn't work to find my phantom cards:
-introduced:1000 introduced:2000

This must mean there's a bug in the database. So after backing it up, I opened the database file in ~/.local/share/Anki2/User 1/collection.anki2 with DB browser and navigated to the revlog table.
You can read the documentation here: https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android/wiki/Database-Structure to understand what the columns mean. I sorted by the id column, which does not refer to the note id this time, but instead refers to the review time in milliseconds since the unix epoch.

After deleting the offending rows, my problem went away. I searched the card ids with cid:1594741131629 and they don't exist. That's why my introduced search filter wasn't working.
Now my question is, what caused these bad database rows in the first place? If anyone reading this has one of the card ids listed in the cid table please comment below and let me know what those mystery cards are.
